# Filewatcher FIRST Renamed event after 15 seconds of inactivity will not be captured

Tags: c#, file-rename, file-watcher

I'm pretty sure that I have exhausted all my options before posting here and I have spent hours trying to search for an answer (and of course testing out my code).

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. Code is compiled and run with Mono-Develop. I need my application to run on a Linux.

I am trying to capture all file events (Created, Deleted, Changed, Renamed). I start by using the exact example from MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.renamed(v=vs.110).aspx) as follow:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;

public class Watcher
{

    public static void Main()
    {
    Run();

    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
    public static void Run()
    {
        string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        // If a directory is not specified, exit program.
        if(args.Length != 2)
        {
            // Display the proper way to call the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: Watcher.exe (directory)");
            return;
        }

        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = args[1];
        /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
           the renaming of files or directories. */
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        // Only watch text files.
        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // Wait for the user to quit the program.
        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while(Console.Read()!='q');
    }

    // Define the event handlers.
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
       Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
    }

    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
    }
}
```

What I kept getting is that if my first file event is a Renamed, the above code does NOT capture it. Instead, it captures a Created event of the new file name, and a Deleted event of the old file name. HOWEVER, when I rename the same file, or another file, only then does the above code capture the next rename event correctly. Now, if I leave the program idle for 15 seconds and execute a new file renamed, the code instead captures *again* a Created event of the new file name, followed by a Deleted event of the old file name.

I also tried to execute other file events, like Created or Deleted. Only after executing any of these events, will the Renamed event be captured after I attempt to rename the file. I am able to consistently reproduce the above results every time.

I definitely have to get the Renamed event happen every single time a file is renamed, so I cannot simply accept the Created and Deleted alternative. I hope to find out what is the cause of the above results. I'm not able to understand why this is happening even from reading the MSDN documents (sorry if it was explained, it just probably isn't explicit enough to me).

Has this got anything to do with `FileSystemEventHandler` needing to happen first before `RenamedEventHandler` can take effect? If so, how can I navigate around this?

Appreciate also if anyone can advise how to achieve the Renamed event being captured **every time** a file or directory is renamed.